# why is the clock of my atmega16 not working correctly, has anything to be configured?

Tags: avr, atmega16

i haven't connected any oscillator circuit in my atmega16. But doesn't it have to work on it's default clocks? Please answer me, if any other configurations are required or settings have to be done in dumper program itself? I am using code vision avr and it generates codes itself, i also tried avrstudio code, but it didn't work! I am as a beginner trying to make a digital clock on 16x2 lcd, lcd stuff is okay! the timer has a problem, it's not showing the correct resolution!

Comment: maybe if you posted some code here? What programmer sw and hw do you use?

Answer (score 0):

1. hw issues, ensure that you have at least 100nF folium capacitor between power and GND on your atmega16. Do you have it? You should have larger electrolytic filtering capacitor like 100uF for your whole project. Do you have high enough voltage to run your clock frequncy? Check your datasheet for the required voltage.
2. read your fuses to determine if you have internal oscilator configured and determine what internal clock frequency you should have, then review your code if it makes more sense.
   [There](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&p=544649) is some link for checking fuses directly from code vision

Answer (score 0):

Set Fuse bit to a particular frequency before burning your code at which you want to work.You can use khazama for this purpose